# PostgreSQL, ODBC and temp table

Tags: postgresql, odbc

Could you tell me why this query works in pgAdmin, but doesn't with software using ODBC:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp296 WITH (OIDS) ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT age_group AS a,male AS m,mode AS t,AVG(speed) AS speed
FROM person JOIN info ON person.ppid=info.ppid
WHERE info.mode=2
GROUP BY age_group,male,mode;

SELECT age_group,male,mode,
CASE 
WHEN age_group=1 AND male=0 THEN (info_dist_km/(SELECT avg_speed FROM temp296 WHERE a=1 AND m=0))*60
ELSE 0
END AS info_durn_min
FROM person JOIN info ON person.ppid=info.ppid
WHERE info.mode IN (7) AND info.info_dist_km>2;
```

I got "42P01: ERROR: relation "temp296" does not exist".

I also have tried with "BEGIN; [...] COMMIT;" - "HY010:The cursor is open".

PostgreSQL 9.0.10, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 64-bit
psqlODBC 09.01.0200
Windows 7 x64

Comment: can you rewrite the query from using a temp table to a CTE?  Do you still get an error in that case?

Comment: I am not familiar with CTE-I've just replaced whole **CREATE** line with **WITH temp296 AS (** and I put **)** before the second **SELECT**. Is this correct? Now it works. Two questions:why isn't **CREATE TEMP TABLE** version OK?How does CTE behave in the environment with many connections at the same time(using the same credentials)-wouldn't users overwrite results of the first **SELECT**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the reason why it did not work for you because by default ODBC works in autocommit mode. If you executed your statements serially, the very first statement

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp296 ON COMMIT DROP ... ;
```

must have autocommitted after finishing, and thus dropped your temp table.

Unfortunately, ODBC does not support directly using statements like `BEGIN TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT;` to handle transactions.

Instead, you can disable auto-commit using [SQLSetConnectAttr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713605.aspx) function like this:

```
SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF, 0);
```

But, after you do that, you must remember to commit any change by using [SQLEndTran](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716544.aspx) like this:

```
SQLEndTran(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc, SQL_COMMIT);
```

While WITH approach has worked for you as a workaround, it is worth noting that using transactions appropriately is faster than running in auto-commit mode.

For example, if you need to insert many rows into the table (thousands or millions), using transactions can be hundreds and thousand times faster than autocommit.

Comment: Sounds good to me, but at the present moment I am not able to use extra functions in software I am using. I am contacting the developers and hope that they will figure out how to run this function. I will post the results.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to do this in VB/VBA for Informix ODBC driver?

Comment: I don't think VBA provides any way to call C API functions I mentioned to begin and commit transactions: `SQLSetConnectAttr()` and `SQLEndTran()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon for temporary tables to not be available via SQLPrepare/SQLExecute in ODBC i.e., on prepared statements e.g., MS SQL Server is like this. The solution is usually to use SQLExecDirect.