# How to select from temp table with ODBC in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, odbc, ado, informix

I'm writing an Excel tool which queries Informix DB server with ODBC driver. The SQL string is made up in VBA. Since the query is complicated, intermediate results are saved in temp tables. When I ran the real query today, it said "The specified table is not in the database."

[PostgreSQL, ODBC and temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086994/postgresql-odbc-and-temp-table) this question suggests it's because by default ODBC works in autocommit mode. So how can I change this in my VBA program? Thank you.

Comment: try to add to your connection string AutoCommit=False or AutoCommit=0, please inform if one or the other works ( some drivers have also Auto commit=0).

Comment: @Archlight Hi, I tried AutoCommit=False, AutoCommit=0, Auto commit=False and Auto commit=0, and none of them works. :( The driver I use is IBM Informix Client SDK 4.10 TC3DE.

Comment: have you tried wrapping it in transaction?

Comment: Are all the queries executed in the same session?  Because temp tables are session specific, and it looks like when you query your temp table, you're working in a different session.

Comment: @Archlight I tried ADO's `Connection.BeginTrans` method, and also `begin work;`, `commit work;` in SQL. Nothing changed. A post somewhere else suggests configuring an ODBC DSN, and setting the _Cursor Behavior_ as _1 - Preserve_. I've done that, and am now facing a _Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed_ error. Actually this error always existed, but was ignored until I suspect it's related to the problem of selecting from temp table.

Comment: @Copilot It seems ADO or ODBC driver makes multiple queries in split sessions. I'm fighting to try to control this behavior.

Comment: I hesitate to recomend this, but before we had temp tables we made them ourselfs _tempTable_34989r98938493 <= guid and then dropping them...

Comment: @Archlight I don't know if I understand the __tempTable_34989r98938493 <= guid_ part correctly. Is it a temp table name as an example? You mean maybe the temp table doesn't exist? I use `select into temp` statement, and have also tried `create temp table`. It doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I'm on the edge of giving up since no new info could be found. I believe the problem is in the config of the ODBC driver or perhaps ADO.